# Let $\{v_1, v_2,...,v_n\}$ be a basis for an inner product space V. Show that the zero vector...

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, inner-products

> Let $\{v_1, v_2,...,v_n\}$ be a basis for an inner product space V. Show that the zero vector is the only vector in V that is orthogonal to all the basis vectors.

Let $v$ be any nonzero vector in V. $v$ is a linear combination of the basis vectors of V:
$$v = k_1v_1 + k_2v_2+ ... + k_nv_n$$
Therefore, for each basis vector $v_i$, the inner product with any vector in V is:
$$\langle k_1v_1 + k_2v_2 + \ldots + k_nv_n,v_i\rangle = \langle k_1v_1,v_i\rangle + \langle k_2v_2,v_i \rangle + \ldots + \langle k_iv_i,v_i \rangle + \ldots + \langle k_nv_n,v_i\rangle $$

This can only equal zero if all the basis vectors are zero. But this does not make sense because they would not form a basis of V and also because $v$ is non-zero.

Therefore no non-zero vector $v$ is orthogonal to all the basis vectors of V. However, for each basis vector $v_i$:
$$\langle 0,v_i \rangle = 0$$
Therefore the $0$ vector is orthogonal to all basis vectors $\{v_1, v_2,...,v_n\}$.

Verification and improvement would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't follow your reasoning in the statement that starts "this can only equal zero if...".  But of course we know $<v,v>=0 \iff v = 0 $ and that's enough to complete the argument.

Comment: I think I'm following what you're saying there @lulu. The only way that long inner product expression would equal zero was if $v$ was the zero vector and so I would just need to write what you said immediately after this expression?

Comment: Yes.  Each inner product $<k_iv_i,v.=0$ by assumption.  That means that $<v,v>=0$ which means that $v=0$.

Comment: Thanks for your help @lulu